# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')? how to solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

- Can anyone help to solve this issue I can't get what wrong with code !!!!

1. [This one is javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHq5i.png)
2. [Html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROVx7.png)
3. [Error shows in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGj5w.png)

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting *pictures* of code or error messages.

Comment: Don't post pictures of your code/errors, that makes helping you harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.querySelector(".drum") selects the first element with class "drum" so the {i} is useless, use querySelectorAll.

Comment: i'd also recomment using .forEach instead of for loop, [JS forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks for your help it woks well now.

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned in this post: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)
, you should not upload image of your code. You should prefer embed your code with code tag when you ask question on stackoverflow.
In this way, people can answer you more easily.

In your case your using bad javascript function, you should use `querySelectorAll` in place of `querySelector` if you want to select all your button that have the `drum` class.

`querySelector` select and return the first match of the condition as it said in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: I have one more doubt should I really need to learn jquery? I am getting confused.

Comment: You should be able to read it for understanding solutions that you can find on internet, it helps when you are stuck with something and the only response is in jquery. For more help you can use jquery documentation https://api.jquery.com/, or use translator such as https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/.

Here it is basic JS, vanilla JS, so you dont need to know jquery for understanding this solution.